# Updating elixir map

Tags: elixir

Have it:

```
[%{"id" => "1", "name" => "foo"},
 %{"id" => "2","name" => "bar"}]
```

How to transform it to something like this:

```
[%"foo" => %{"id" => "1","name" => "foo"},
 %"bar" => {"id" => "2","name" => "bar"}]
```

Comment: The second snippet is invalid syntax. Did you mean `%{"foo" => ..., "bar" => ...}`?

Comment: What have you tried? None of us can help you unless I have something to work with, in particular a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A great way to explain this is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Also, do check out the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931) and [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a `Map` with `String` keys, you can use `for` with `into:` like this:

```
iex(1)> entries = [%{"id" => "1", "name" => "foo"}, %{"id" => "2","name" => "bar"}]
[%{"id" => "1", "name" => "foo"}, %{"id" => "2", "name" => "bar"}]
iex(2)> for %{"name" => name} = entry <- entries, into: %{}, do: {name, entry}
%{"bar" => %{"id" => "2", "name" => "bar"},
  "foo" => %{"id" => "1", "name" => "foo"}}
```